# Any way to get new ProgressBar design for Android?

Tags: android, material-design

With Google Material Design 2.0, Google introduced a new ProgressBar, which has a brand-new animation, new color profiles, and new look.

Here is a screenshot representing what it looks like: [image: Google New ProgressBar]

Here is a recorded video about the animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQe0A.jpg

I tried to get this design on Android by changing the color on Material ProgressBar, but I can't get the animation the new design has.

Is it possible to get this ProgressBar?

Comment: I don't think that's actually the stock MD2 ProgressBar, which I'm pretty sure is the same as MD1. Google just made its own.

Comment: IF you're looking for a library, your question is off topic.  If you're looking to implement it yourself, be specific on what part of it you're having trouble with, and provide what you have so far.

Comment: @GabeSechan it's just a progressbar we know. but I wonder if I missed any styles.

Comment: @TheWanderer ah, i thought it was the stock new progressbar. seems it is impossible to get the progressbar design.

Comment: Did you make it or not yet, I need it too.